# styled-components how to apply styling when the components have a different parent tag

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

I use material ui and realized an interesting fact.

Here is the `DatePicker` component that has the `TextField` component and clicking the icon in that component opens the calendar dialog.

When I open the developer tool, it looks like this.

[image]

The parent of the `TextField` component is `<div id='root'>`

However, the parent of the calendar dialog is `<body data-new-gr-c-s-check-loaded="14.1103.0" data-gr-ext-installed="" cz-shortcut-listen="true">`

So how can I apply css via the `DatePicker` component? Is that possible?

Here is a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/basicdatepicker-material-demo-forked-42osb0?file=/demo.js:0-694)

```
import * as React from "react";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import { AdapterDateFns } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDateFns";
import { LocalizationProvider } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider";
import { DatePickerStyled } from "./styles";

export default function BasicDatePicker() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(null);

  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
      <DatePickerStyled
        label="Basic example"
        value={value}
        onChange={(newValue) => {
          setValue(newValue);
        }}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}
```

I'm trying to overwrite stylings from the `DatePicker` component like this(I use styled-component)

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import { DatePicker } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker";

export const DatePickerStyled = styled(DatePicker)`
  & .MuiPickersPopper-root {
    & .MuiPickersPopper-root {
      border: 4px solid red;
      position: absolute;
      left: -23px;
      top: 4px;
      right: 0;
    }
  }
`;

DatePickerStyled.displayName = "DatePickerStyled";
```

Comment: It looks like you are close to figuring things out. By using selectors on a (grand)parent element, you can drill down to select descendant elements. If you can identify a specific styling change you would like to see, please let me know and I will try to offer a solution.